# How can I specify an interval number using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have to check if a variable (php, preg_match) is from 1988 and 2011 using regex; I know how to do it with normal if/else, but I'd like to use regex for this!

Comment: What do you mean by `if a variable (php, preg_match) is from 1988 and 2011`? That translates to something really silly in English, so you might want to reword it :)

Comment: I suggest you use the right tool for the job... if/else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, regular expressions are not the only answer:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{4}$/', $input) && $input >= 1988 && $input <= 2011) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't be that easy, as regex is meant to match character by character. You could use something like this (probably wouldn't be a good idea).

```
/(198[89]|199\d|200\d|201[01])/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this using regex?

One solution could be something along the lines of `(?:198[8-9]|199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace_callback :

```
<?php
preg_replace_callback('%([0-9]{4})%', function($match) {
    $number = $match[1];
    if($number < 1988 || $number > 2011) return; /* Discard the match */
    /* Return the replacement here */
}, $input);
```

This is in my opinion the most flexible solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/^[12][90][8901][8901]\z/
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Would validate a `1000` or a `2999` which are out of the desired range. You have to specify the possibilities refining from each intermediate position.